# Global unchangeable variables

Tags: c#

So I created a new c# project, of the Windows form variety.

There are a couple of numbers which appear across the classes in the project, which are set and don't change. They're actually unicode IDs for certain characters, and so changing them wouldn't make sense anyway. So in my code, the numbers 12449 and 12540 will appear at various points (as well as a few others). The problem for me is that this doesn't make the code very readable. Sure I can add comments, but I was hoping for something a little neater.

I have looked up #defines, but c# doesn't have those, so is there a way to have a global unchangeable variable which I can access across various classes within the project?

Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you group them in a class "Globals" or something and declare it as const ?

Comment: How about add a static class and define these variables there?

Comment: Thanks, a static class worked. I wasn't sure I could do it that way, but it seems I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [const](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) keyword for this purpose.

You can set tham as

```
public const int CertainId1 = 12449;
public const int CertainId2 = 12540;
```

You can access them, but can not change tham at any point of code at all.